# jshint: 'use the function form of "use strict"' and 'document is not defined' in simple javascript file

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have bundled these together because I think they are related.
The most simplest of simple bits of code:

```
'use strict';
const x = document.querySelector('#score strong');
```

is resulting in the following

```
"use the function form of use strict (W097)"
"document is not defined (W117)"
```

which may be errors or warnings; the W suggests a warning but I don't know how to determine this.

So, another question: **are these warnings, or errors, and how can I tell this for myself**?  Where is this referenced?

I am using Atom 1.31, with I think JSHint (whatever that is - I am new to all this). I am using ES6 - .jshintrc:

```
{
"esversion": 6
}
```

How should I be specifying use strict globally? Putting it in a function so that it's used globally means, er, putting the whole contents of my script inside a function. No? Yes?

And how do I circumvent this document is not defined thing?
I have tried

```
const document=this.document;
const document=global.document;
const document=window.document;
```

All result in warnings/errors (whatever).

So, to be clear, my questions are:

1. are these warnings, or errors, and how can I tell this for myself?
2. how do I and indeed do I need to, circumvent the use strict thing?
3. how do I and indeed do I need to, circumvent the document is not defined thing?

Comment: 1) These are warnings created from the static analysis of your code by the linting feature of Atom. They are warnings because JSHint (the linting ruleset) cannot read your mind about where you might use this code. So it does the best is can to say _Hey! You might want to take an extra look at this!_. Your code may or may not work regardless of these errors. Now that you know it is JSHint, read the docs: https://jshint.com/docs/

Comment: Many people just turn off many of these rules. That is not recommended. Understanding the rules will make you a better JavaScript programmer!

Comment: Your question is a question and it should still be a question in the future. Don't edit in answers please.

Comment: @RandyCasburn if you know a good answer, answer ... I edited your comment into the community wiki, feel free to rollback :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’ll need to set the [`strict` option](https://jshint.com/docs/options/#strict) to prefer a global `'use strict'`, and the [`browser` option](https://jshint.com/docs/options/#browser) to tell JSHint that your script targets browsers.

**.jshintrc**

```
{
    "esversion": 6,
    "browser": true,
    "strict": "global"
}
```

And yes, “W” at the beginning of a code means “warning”.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now. I actually found the (a/another) solution to use strict immediately after posting this question, so I've edited it, but I'll also try your way.

Comment: @JL_SO: JSHint defaults to wanting an IIFE, but honestly, that’s bad advice. There’s no reason not to use a top-level strict pragma unless you bundle scripts by concatenating them.

Comment: thanks. IIFE - I just had to look that up.  I will read up on it. BTW I tried your jshintrc k/v pairs and they don't work for me: I still get both warnings. What works for the strict mode warning is using `/*jslint node: true */` The document warning remains unfixed.

Comment: @JL_SO: Are you sure you changed the right .jshintrc? `/* jshint browser: true */` and `"browser": true` in a .jshintrc should do exactly the same thing. (Also, `node: true` isn’t correct unless you’re writing a script intended to work in both Node.js and the browser.)

Comment: Yes, I changed the .jshintrc file - the one in the question that had/has one line in it, specifying es6.  The /*..*/ hints as posted in the solution are just copied and pasted from the top of my js file.  Both warnings have disappeared.

Comment: No! You're right. Sorry I thought maybe you meant, did I change a file by a similar but different name, but I had the same named file but in a different project folder open...Durrrrr!!!!  Yes, I can confirm your solution works as well. I will update my question and give you the green tick. Apologies.  Thanks.

Comment: @JL_SO: Glad to hear the mystery’s solved :D I had been experimenting furiously trying to reproduce it.